# Windows 10 Bluetooth is off and devices show as not connected

Tags: audio, configuration, bluetooth, windows-10, driver

Something strange has happened to my Lenovo IdeaPad 310 with Windows 10 latest updates.

My Bluetooth headset was working fine.
But now the toggle to switch Bluetooth on/off has gone missing.

Settings > Bluetooth and other devices

> Bluetooth on/off toggle is missing

Settings > Bluetooth and other devices > Senheiser MB Pro 2

> Bluetooth is turned off

My headset is listed as a Bluetooth device but the buttons "Connect" and "Remove device" are both disabled.

Device Manager > View > Show hidden devices

The Bluetooth section contains four entries :

```
Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)
Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth 4.1
```

All have a faded blue Bluetooth icon.

Right-click on any of them has the same message :

> Currently this hardware device is not connected to the computer (
> Cede 45 ).  To fix this problem, reconnect the hardware device to the
> computer.

Right-click any of them and select "Update driver" :

> The best drivers for your device are already installed.
>
> Windows has determined that the best driver for this device is already
> installed. There may be better drivers on Windows Update or on the
> device manufacturer's website.

Troubleshoot > Bluetooth > Run the troubleshooter

> Device does not have Bluetooth
>
> Bluetooth is not available on this device. Please try using an
> external adapter to add Bluetooth capability to this computer.

I restarted my PC but doesn't seem to have any effect.

I checked for Windows Updates but it does not find any new updates.

I used the Lenovo Service Bridge utility to scan my system and check for any updated drivers but it says I'm up-to-date.  I went ahead and downloaded the Bluetooth driver package `75l804af086x.exe` and did a manual install and then power-off / power-on but nothing has changed - I'm still on `Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Bluetooth 4.1`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes with windows updates, few things get broken mostly happen with my wireless driver. You can try reinstalling bluetooth drivers or you can remove the one installed and check in windows updates if there is any updates for bluetooth.
After this shutdown your system(important not restart, shutdown). On reboot your bluetooth will be working fine.(works for my wireless driver). Give it a try

Comment: Are you saying to right-click each of the four listed Bluetooth devices and select `Uninstall device` then `Shutdown` then press power-button to startup ?

Comment: Don't check it in device manager, press windows + i (settings) in that apps, there you can find bluetooth or you can remove it from control panel.

Comment: For me `Settings > Bluetooth and other devices` is missing the toggle to switch Bluetooth on/off -- that's the problem : I can't turn on Bluetooth and so Windows thinks all the Bluetooth devices are not connected.

Comment: Check windows updates if there is any update. If not, then install your bluetooth driver it will fix missing files, 'Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377' this is your bluetooth device.

Comment: I reinstalled the latest driver and power-off power-on but nothing has changed.

Comment: You can try the other methods mentioned on below URL: https://www.ubackup.com/articles/how-to-fix-error-code-45-0040.html

Answer (score 2):

This solution fixed the issue on my Dell which has the same Bluetooth chip.
https://www.dell.com/community/XPS-Desktops/XPS-8930-Qualcomm-QCA9377-Bluetooth-failures/m-p/7402161#M28463

> I shutdown the XPS 8930, unplugged the power cord for a few minutes, then powered it back on. I then went to Device Manager and uninstalled the Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed). When I then did a Scan for Hardware Changes, the Bluetooth appeared in Device Manager. This resolved the issue.